# How do I handle a component with pin spacings smaller than the necessary trace width?

Tags: pcb-design, trace

I'm designing a board using a TPS2113 power mux in a TTSOP package to deliver ~1A from plug power or a battery to my board. My calculated trace width for this current is 25-30 mil, however the pins of this component are spaced 25 mil apart, making it difficult to connect wide traces. The IC pins are ~11mil wide. How do I handle this, and how is it possible that such narrow pins are intended to carry such a large current? The TPS2113 is rated for 1.3A maximum.

Comment: Do you have space in your layout to use a short run of too-narrow trace to break out to a spot where you can fit a wider trace? If so, you may be able to get away with a short narrow trace, as heat will be conducted into the wider traces and then dissipated to the atmosphere. I'm looking for an existing answer on this site as I've almost certainly seen this discussed here before, but I haven't been able to locate it yet.

Comment: @nanofarad One of those questions that's slower to search for than to just answer, so ends up duplicated regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace current handling (ampacity) only matters over long distances, where heat isn't being sunk along the length of the trace.

As long as you make the connection (fanout) short, and attach it to a much thicker trace or pour, it's fine for the fanout to be ~pad sized.

After all, they have microscopic bondwires inside the package; those work just fine too (being short, and surrounded by encapsulant). :)